# express routing calling a class

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, routes

I'm learning express js and wanted to do a basic saving documents with it. So i have a dropzone that allow me to upload a Excel file. All i want to do its a basic parse of the excel in order to save some data in postgreSQL database.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fileupload = require("express-fileupload");
router.use(fileupload());
import { Parser } from "../src/Controller/Parser";
//var Parse = require('../src/Controller/Parser'); // this throws -> Cannot find module '../src/Controller/Parser'

router.post('/sourceParser', function (req, res) {
    console.log('file: ', req.files.file.data) // buffer with the excel file

    let parser = new Parser()
    parser.sourceParser(req.files.file.data);

    return res.status(200).send('File uploaded') // file[0].data
});

module.exports = router;
```

And this is the error im getting:

```
import { Parser } from "../src/Controller/Parser";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

edit, adding Parse class source

```
class Parser {

    constructor(){
    }

    sourceParser(binaryStr: string | ArrayBuffer | null){
        // ...
    }
}

module.exports = Parser;
```

So my question is how can i call a class 'Parser' inside a router? any suggestion are really appreciated
thx!

Answer (score 0):

import your class as the following:

```
const Parser = require("./../src/Controller/Parser");
```

Comment: Error: Cannot find module '../Controller/Parser' (i changed the path thinking it was something like that but no clue)

Comment: Can you try with the following synthax ?